# Why is System.out.println(super) not permitted?

Tags: java, oop, tostring

Why is `System.out.println(super)` not permitted?

```
System.out.println(this);
```

This is OK and `this.toString()` is called and printed automatically.
Of course, instance variable is OK instead of `this`.

However, `this` and `super` can be used in same way as I know.

```
System.out.println(super);
```

So why does this fail? I think it's supposed to call `super.toString()` implicitly.
I have read Java specification document, but I haven't found the reason.

Comment: How does it fail? Is it a compilation error? A runtime exception? or unexpected behavior? (e.g. `System.out.println(super)` prints the same thing as `this.toString()`)

Comment: The problem is that compile error occurred from second case using 'super'. Error message is " '.' expected " and it looks like a syntax error.

Comment: *"It's a simple question."*  Note that "What is the meaning of life?" is a simple question.  It is the answer that is harder.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew I got it. I didn't recognize that, lol. The answers are interesting and useful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a standalone variant of `super` that breaks virtual method dispatch would be an extremely bad idea.

Let's think about it for a while.

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract String Description();
    String toString() { return "Base"; }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    String Description() { return "Derived description"; }
    String toString() { return "Derived"; }

    static void use(Base instance) {
        System.out.println(instance.toString());
        System.out.println(instance.Description());
    }
}
```

Now, let us take your suggestion and suppose that `super` is valid and does what you suggest; then we may write in `Derived`:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    // Previous declarations omitted.
    void useSuper() { Derived.use(super); }
    void useThis() { Derived.use(this); }

    static void main() {
        Derived instance = new Derived();
        instance.useThis();
        instance.useSuper();
    }
}
```

Now, if I understood you, you suggest that the main function should print in order:

- the implementation of `toString()` from `Derived`: "Derived".
- the implementation of `Description()` from `Derived`: "Derived description"
- the implementation of `toString()` from `Base`: "Base".
- the implementation of `Description()` from `Base`: *It does not exist.* And the two solutions I can think of leads to bigger problems:

  - Raise an exception: congratulations, you can now break any program which relies on abstract methods actually being implemented without even thinking about it. (How would you know that a function will call the abstract method?)
  - Return the implementation from `Derived`: breaks consistency.

In short, such a use of the word `super` conceptually breaks object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 8):

Check the grammar at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/syntax.doc.html

The `super` keywords must always be followed by SuperSuffix, which cannot be empty.

So `super` can never stand alone as an expression.

Comment: for one second I was thinking it was possible so I was written a small program to test it :S

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to your current **object**.  `super` refers to the super **class**, the class your current object directly inherits from (or it can be the super's constructor).  So

```
System.out.println(this)
```

prints your object's toString() method, but

```
System.out.println(super)
```

fails because super is NOT an object (and thus has no toString() method).

Comment: To further clarify, `super` refers to a class, which does have a toString() method, but the method is not static; it cannot be invoked at the class level. It needs to be called on an object, like `this`.

Comment: If you think about it, even is super was an object, it would be the same object as this.

Comment: @StevenNoto, if super refers to a class and which does not have a static toString() method then how this code `System.out.println(super.toString());` works?

Answer (score -5):

Super is relevant for calling of static methods only. If you call non-static method using super that is actually reference to your object itself, i.e. to `this`. For example you can say `System.out.println(super.toString())`. This will work and will run the `toString()` of actual class.

I think this is the reason that passing `super` as argument to other method is forbidden.

Comment: No, calling non-static method using super will also work. toString is not a static method, and calling super.toString() will correctly call the the ancestor class's toString().

Comment: I said that it works. But it calls the toString() of actual class, not its super class!

Comment: Pretty sure that's false.  You might want to actually test this on simple classes, I did and got that it called the super class's method.

Comment: That's what I did to be sure. I created class A and class B extends A. Class B has method foo() that calls super.toString() and gets toString() of B. This is called metamorphism, man, the basics of OOP.

Comment: Did you override the `toString()` of `B`? And I believe it is polymorphism, not metamorphism.

Comment: First, do you mean polymorphism?  Secondly, that's interesting because I did the exact same thing and got that it was calling Class A's toString().  Have you tried calling super.toString() inside of B's toString()?  If what you say is true, you'll be stuck in an infinite loop when you try to run it.  If I'm right, you'll just call A's toString().

Comment: I mean polymorphism. I was misspelling

Comment: The use of the super key word *is* to ensure that instead of calling this.method(), which would be called if you simply called method(), you have a way of calling the ancestor class method. static methods do NOT exhibit polymorphism, and so its advised to call them with their class names (A.method() instead of this.method() or instance.method().) Also used to call the immediate parent's constructor withing the child class's constructor (as first statement in the constructor body.)