# Is super a reference variable in java?

Tags: java, super

How can we write S.O.P(super.x) which should only be possible if super was a reference variable?

Is super a reference variable?

If not, does it mean that we can access non static data members stored in objects without the following syntax `"reference variable"."data member"`?

Comment: super is a keyword, not a variable.

Comment: i read it from here that it is a reference variable also http://www.javatpoint.com/super-keyword

Comment: @vibhukapoor That tells a lot about the (lack of) quality of that website. You may want to avoid it in the future.

Comment: Okay Accepted,that super is not a reference variable but then how can we access data members using super as i asked in the second part of my question

Comment: Check the answer in [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786102/why-is-system-out-printlnsuper-not-permitted)

Comment: @vibhukapoor Because that's how it's defined. The answer to your `how` is `because`, and that's it.

Comment: @Kayaman so can we say that Super keyword is an exception and data members accessed using super do not require any reference variable?

Comment: @vibhukapoor No we can't say that `super` is an exception. It works exactly as intended, designed and documented. Its use is defined by the Java language syntax and its inner working is handled by the JVM. Just because it looks like a reference variable if you don't know what it is doesn't make it one.

Comment: @Stultuske , `this` is also a keyword but refers to the current instance and it has its own static-type ( type of the reference of `this` ) and dynamic-type ( type of the object ) , so it implicitly defines a variable. The question can be phrased as - does `super` implicitly define a variable? ( as in the case for `this` )

Answer (score 0):

Few points about `super`

1.) `super` is a keyword in java

2.) A `static` or `instance` variable in a `subclass` may have the same name as a `superclass` variable. In this case, the variable hides the `superclass` variable and it can have same type or different types.

3.) It is possible to access `hidden variable` by `super` keyword.

4.) Note that super keyword enables you to access the superclass variable and construct a subclass by using the same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly access super class variable.

For Example

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Super class variable scope will based its access [modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)